# Ubuntu 19.10 Minecraft Low FPS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

I changed my OS to Ubuntu after seeing my GPU is working properly. 
Minecraft Version 1.8.9 Optifine Installed All low or disabled except fast render, fast math etc.
FPS 40-60 Sometimes Drop To 10 For Half A Second. Using OpenJDK-JRE 8. Launcher command :

`DRI_PRIME=1 sudo java -jar launcher.jar`

Tried with and without sudo same performance.
Smooth FPS disabled makes FPS low.
System Info:
 Intel I3 6006U / HD Graphics 520 / AMD Radeon R5 M330 / 3.6 GB RAM (-Xmx1532M)

Minecraft uses GPU. GPU driver radeon. Never Tried amdgpu. Don't know how to use it.

Comment: What is the performance of other graphically intensive programs?

Comment: This is technically off-topic, as tech support for modded Minecraft, but it also happens to me in Vanilla and the solution is simple (if it's possible), so I'll not to vote to close.

Comment: @FabianRöling Exactly, hence my question, but it seems it was, given the answer. If you think it's helpful information for vanilla Minecrafters as well, maybe you can ask and answer a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable your boot logo, unlike what you wrote in [your own answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/368684/171580). Instead, it's just the command in step 10 that makes Minecraft actually use the GPU instead of just the CPU.

I had the same problem, occasional bad performance, in my case in Vanilla Minecraft. The solution was to start the game with `prime-run minecraft-launcher` instead of just `minecraft-launcher`.

The specific Linux distribution also needs to support the GPU, for example Debian 9 did not support my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, but Manjaro 19 did, using the driver "video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime" (installed by default).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i found a solution.
I am going to explain to everyone here step by step what to do.

1. Use `sudo lshw -c video` on a terminal and look for your GPU.
2. Find configuration: driver=
3. if after driver= you see radeon then you can skip 4. if don't read 4.
4. if after driver= you see amdgpu or amdgpu-pro this will not solve your problem. Sorry.
5. type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` to terminal (change gedit to your preffered text editor)
6. You need to find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
7. put `adeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon` next to the `quiet splash`
   it should look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon"`
8. type `sudo update-grub2` to terminal
9. Restart
10. When oppening an application that you want it to use GPU open a terminal and type `DRI_PRIME=1 yourapplicationstartthing`(in my example `DRI_PRIME=1 java -jar launcher.jar` do this when you are at the location of launcher.jar like Desktop)
11. DO NOT USE SUDO WHEN LAUNCHING YOUR APPLICATION/GAME.

Hope it helps